# Get a specific class from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a project in which I need to add a ton of objects to an ArrayList and then call specific functions in them later on. I have this part down but in my program I need to access specific instances from the ArrayList with only the parameter of the class I am looking for.
For example:

```
public class Manager {
    public static ArrayList<O> loadedHacks = new ArrayList<O>();
    public void initOs(){
        loadedHacks.add(new O());
    }
}

public class O {
    public boolean enabled = false;
    public void onEnable(){}
}

public class A extends O{
}
```

Then later I want to do something like this:

```
if(Helper.get(A.class).enabled){}
```

Comment: I've provided an answer to the question I *think* you're asking, but you should ideally try and clarify how you ask questions! For example, you mention ArrayList, but there is no mention of any ArrayList in your example code that is supposed to be exposing the problem you are trying to solve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear from your question what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve, but if I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is say: "object X could be of some subclass of class A. If it's subclass B, then I want to call B.method(), which isn't defined on A".

In which, case you can do something like this:

```
if (object instanceof SpecificSubclass) {
  SpecificSubclass specificObject = (SpecificSubclass) object;
  specificObject.specificMethod();
}
```

**EDIT:** from your comment, it seems the functionality you're looking for is slightly different. If you have as a parameter a Class, then to see if a particular object is in effect an instance of that class, use the Class.isAssignableFrom() method.

Comment: Basically my question is what would I do in the method getHack? How do I scan an ArrayList for only the param I gave it?

Comment: OK, what in words of the English language do you want the method getHack() to actually do?

Comment: I edited the code to make it a bit clearer. getHack() should be able to recieve a class as its parameter and then look through the ArrayList loadedHacks to find the same class and return it.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer. You basically need to call clz.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()).

Comment: I'm still not 100% where the ArrayList fits into the actual problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you would have to iterate over the ArrayList and compare the param you have as a Class object with the return type of the getClass() within the array, to get the object and return it. Since the getClass() method returns the Class type of the object, not the reference.

Comment: public Hack getHack(Class hackClass){
  for(Hack h : loadedHacks){
   if(hackClass.getClass().equals(h.getClass())){
    return h;
   }
  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: the equals will compare object reference so i'm not sure it will work that way. BUT you can compare the toString() of both with an equals if both are instances of a Class type they have to return the same String. but dont use the getClass() of the the already Class parameter, you should compare like this `hackClass.toString() == h.getClass().toString()`

Comment: or something like this : `h.getClass().isAssignableFrom(hackClass)`